# WordPress plugin- counting posts

Tags: wordpress

My code was working properly, but accidentally I deleted something, but I don't remember what. At this moment my plugin display only one, last user. Before everything was ok and plugin could display all users. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
function my_count_posts_by_user(){

    global $wpdb; 
    $result = count_users();
    $total_users = $result['total_users'];

    for($id = 1;$id<=$total_users;$id++){

   $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  AND wp_users.ID = $id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'" , ARRAY_A);
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($result as $x){
    echo'<tr>'; 

    echo'<td>'.'ID: '. $x['ID']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'.'User : '. $x['display_name'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'.'Number of posts :'. $x['Number_of_posts'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WP API functions which will do everything for you.

- [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) function will get all users data just define fields which u require.
- [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) function will get user meta data.

#### A small example

```
 $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
 foreach( $users as $user_id ) {
     print_r( get_user_meta( $user_id->ID ) );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function my_count_posts_by_user(){

    global $wpdb; 
    $result = count_users();
    $total_users = $result['total_users'];

    for($id = 1;$id<=$total_users;$id++){

       $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  AND wp_users.ID = $id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'" , ARRAY_A);


        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($result as $x){
            echo'<tr>'; 
            echo'<td>'.'ID: '. $x['ID']."</td>";
            echo'<td>'.'User : '. $x['display_name'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.'Number of posts :'. $x['Number_of_posts'].'</td>';
            echo'</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```